# how to execute a command on button click using c++

Tags: python, c++, qt-creator

I have created a form using Qt creator. The form has two fields and a button,on click of this button I need to call a python script. So I have added the following code on the click of button:

```
system("python Example.py");
```

When I run the program and click the button it gives me the following error:

```
python :can't open file 'Example.py':[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is because the system command will take you to the directory where the project is created (/home/user/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/build-ProjectOne-Desktop_qt_qt_Version_GCC_64-bit-Debug)  and I have my python file in the home directory.

So is there any way that I can execute this python script using c++. Also the file on my system is in the home directory and it might be in another location on a different system. So I am looking for a way to execute this script irresepctive of the location.

Comment: I would use QProcess instead of system(). With QProcess set the working directory: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory Do this before you execute start().

Comment: Looks like you should send the full path of `Example.py`.  The error message says that Python can't find your file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes I was able to figure out the reason for the error. I am looking for a way to execute the python script irrespective of the file location. Or if the file is in the home folder system("cd $HOME") and then executing the command is also not working.

Comment: Try `system("bash -c \"cd $HOME && python Example.py\"")`

Comment: @drescherjm thanks..it worked. Also is there any way that I can execute it irrespective of the location. Like if the file is at different location on any other system in that case what would be the best way to execute the script.

Comment: How would python know where the script is? I think you need to have your Qt program know this (either by searching or asking the user) and pass that to system() or as I said in my first post use QProcess()

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. I would look into QProcess and try making it work.